# How can I apply a Regex regular expression to each line of a paragraph without using a loop?

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression for a line, that I apply, for example if the line is: aa.bb.cc.q the output is: aa.bb.cc
It basically takes out the latest part.

The regular expression is:

```
re.findall(".*(?=\.)", txt)
```

Now, I have a paragraph that contains many lines, I want to apply this regular expression on each line and get the results in a list. Is there a way to do that without a loop?

Which means that one regular expression that does it all for all the lines?

Example input:

```
aaa.bb.q2
aaa.bb.qcow2
aaa.bb.aaa.cc.pp
```

Expected output:

```
 A list with the following elements: ['aaa.bb', 'aaa.bb', 'aaa.bb.aaa.cc']
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is wrong with `re.findall(".*(?=\.)", txt)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the regex I posted only works for one line. I want a regex that applies this to every line of a paragraph

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Viktor, thanks for caring and willing to help. Text I have is:
aaa.bb.q2
aaa.bb.qcow2
aaa.bb.aaa.cc.pp

Expected result: A list with the following elements:

['aaa.bb', 'aaa.bb', 'aaa.bb.aaa.cc']

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi Wiktor, done.

Comment: `re.findall(r'.+(?=\.)', text)` should work. See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/3TNk86).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
re.findall(r'(.+)\.', text)
```

The `re.findall` will return *all* found occurrences of any 1+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to - and excluding - the last `.` on a line. Note `re.findall` only returns the captured substrings if capturing groups are defined in the pattern and `(.+)` is a capturing group here.

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/3TNk86):

```
import re
rx = r"(.+)\."
test_str = "aaa.bb.q2\naaa.bb.qcow2\naaa.bb.aaa.cc.pp"
print( re.findall(rx, test_str) )
# => ['aaa.bb', 'aaa.bb', 'aaa.bb.aaa.cc']
```